# Posting JSON to send an email with Nodemailer either sends mail but hangs or throws an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, email, nodemailer

I'm working on MERN app with a basic contact form which uses Nodemailer to send an email. I want some sort of response from the server that can be displayed on the front end, such as 'Mail sent' or 'Mail not sent' etc...

This was my first attempt (code from server.js), based on the example [here](https://nodemailer.com/about/):

```
myRoutes.route('/send-mail').post(async function(req, res) {
  let testAccount = await nodemailer.createTestAccount();

  // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: 'smtp.ethereal.email',
      port: 587,
      secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
      auth: {
          user: testAccount.user, // generated ethereal user
          pass: testAccount.pass // generated ethereal password
      }
  });

  let senderName = req.body.senderName;
  let senderEmail = req.body.senderEmail;
  let subject = req.body.subject;
  let message = req.body.message;
  let toEmail = req.body.toEmail;

  // send mail with defined transport object
  let info = await transporter.sendMail({
      from: `"${senderName}" <${senderEmail}>`, // sender address
      to: toEmail, // receiver address
      subject: subject, // Subject line
      text: message, // plain text body
      html: message
  });

  console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);
  // Message sent: <b658f8ca-6296-ccf4-8306-87d57a0b4321@example.com>

  // Preview only available when sending through an Ethereal account
  console.log('Preview URL: %s', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
  // Preview URL: https://ethereal.email/message/WaQKMgKddxQDoou...
});
```

This works (the mail is sent, and the preview URL is logged to the console), but the post request to the server just hangs until it eventually times out. So, since I'd need to do this anyway, to get the responses from the server which will notify the user on the front end, I figured I'd add a callback after the sendMail function.

Code with callback:

```
myRoutes.route('/send-mail').post(async function(req, res) {
  let testAccount = await nodemailer.createTestAccount();

  // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: 'smtp.ethereal.email',
      port: 587,
      secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
      auth: {
          user: testAccount.user, // generated ethereal user
          pass: testAccount.pass // generated ethereal password
      }
  });

  let senderName = req.body.senderName;
  let senderEmail = req.body.senderEmail;
  let subject = req.body.subject;
  let message = req.body.message;
  let toEmail = req.body.toEmail;

  // send mail with defined transport object
  let info = await transporter.sendMail({
      from: `"${senderName}" <${senderEmail}>`, // sender address
      to: toEmail, // receiver address
      subject: subject, // Subject line
      text: message, // plain text body
      html: message
  },function(){
    res.json('Mail sent!');
  }).catch(err => {
    res.json("Couldn't send the mail for some reason");
  });

  console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);
  // Message sent: <b658f8ca-6296-ccf4-8306-87d57a0b4321@example.com>

  // Preview only available when sending through an Ethereal account
  console.log('Preview URL: %s', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
  // Preview URL: https://ethereal.email/message/WaQKMgKddxQDoou...
});
```

This gets a 'Mail sent!' response from server, but the server throws this error: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'catch' of undefined`, and it doesn't log the messageID or the preview url, so I'm not sure if it's actually sent the mail or not.

I tried passing `err` as a parameter to the function before the catch, but that didn't help.

I've also tried removing the catch altogether (see below):

```
myRoutes.route('/send-mail').post(async function(req, res) {
  let testAccount = await nodemailer.createTestAccount();

  // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: 'smtp.ethereal.email',
      port: 587,
      secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
      auth: {
          user: testAccount.user, // generated ethereal user
          pass: testAccount.pass // generated ethereal password
      }
  });

  let senderName = req.body.senderName;
  let senderEmail = req.body.senderEmail;
  let subject = req.body.subject;
  let message = req.body.message;
  let toEmail = req.body.toEmail;

  // send mail with defined transport object
  let info = await transporter.sendMail({
      from: `"${senderName}" <${senderEmail}>`, // sender address
      to: toEmail, // receiver address
      subject: subject, // Subject line
      text: message, // plain text body
      html: message
  },function(){
    res.json('Mail sent!');
  });

  console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);
  // Message sent: <b658f8ca-6296-ccf4-8306-87d57a0b4321@example.com>

  // Preview only available when sending through an Ethereal account
  console.log('Preview URL: %s', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
  // Preview URL: https://ethereal.email/message/WaQKMgKddxQDoou...
});
```

This gets the 'Mail sent!' response again, but the server now throws this error: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'messageId' of undefined`

Any idea how I can get this working? I just want a simple contact form, which, when submitted, sends responses back from the server with a status telling us whether the mail has sent or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot to add return , try this way :

```
let info = await transporter.sendMail({
      from: `"${senderName}" <${senderEmail}>`, // sender address
      to: toEmail, // receiver address
      subject: subject, // Subject line
      text: message, // plain text body
      html: message
  }).then((data)=>{return data}).catch((error)=> {return error});

if(info.messageId){
   console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);
   res.json({message:'Mail sent!'});
}else{
   console.log('Message Not sent');
   res.json({message:'Mail not sent!'});
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @SaurabhMistry. I've tried your code and it does send the mail, but the post request just causes the server to hang and doesn't give a response, just like it does with the code from my first attempt.

Comment: @AT92 , can you add your updated code , so i can check

Comment: @AT92 , please check updated code is working or not ?